# Associating Users with Different Subscriber Keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, user-management

Scenario: Subscribers are added into the Marketing Cloud through two different sources, which each method using it's own ID generator to use as a Subscriber Key. Both sources are uploaded into the same Data Extension.

Problem: This is going to led to a Subscriber base that allows for the same user to exist twice. If a user exists on both sources they would receive two emails. More importantly, if they unsubscribe through one of the two emails they will still be subscribed on the other and may receive further emails, which could pose a bigger problem.

Does a technical solution exist that would mimic the functionality of merging two users? The most viable I've thought it to use queries to create an exclusion list of users deemed duplicates.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, SubscriberKey should be a unique identifier for a subscriber across your entire enterprise.  There is not a feature within the Marketing Cloud which merges subscriber records.  If email address is truly the unique identifier for a subscriber, then that could be used as the Subscriber Key with the IDs from the different sources being stored as profile attributes if they are needed for personalization.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - this is a job best left outside of SFMC, which is fair I'd say. Cheers.